# Is it possible to change the size of a named pipe on Linux?

Tags: linux, ipc, named-pipes

I know that for the current version of the Linux kernel, the size of named pipes is 64K. Is it possible to increase this size at all?

I know I can switch to sockets, but first I'd like to see if I can solve an intermittent buffer-overflow problem by just increasing the named-pipe size.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With recent kernels (>= 2.6.35), you can change the size of a pipe with

```
fcntl(fd, F_SETPIPE_SZ, size)
```

where `size` is a `long`. The maximum size is in `/proc/sys/fs/pipe-max-size`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a 2.6.32 system.

Comment: @larsmans - Is there a bash command available for this on Debian?