# Android USB Host API: bulk transfer buffer size

Tags: android, usb, host

I am writing software to **communicate between tablet** (Motorola Xoom with Android version 4.0.3 and Kernel version 2.6.39.4) **and a peripheral device using USB Host API** provided by Android. I use only two types of communication:

- **control**: `controlTransfer(int requestType, int request, int value, int index, byte[] buffer, int length, int timeout)`
- **bulk**: `bulkTransfer(UsbEndpoint endpoint, byte[] buffer, int length, int timeout)`

Control transfer works fine, but I have **a problem with bulk transfer. I can use only 32768 as a size of the buffer for bulkTransfer function. It is not possible to use less or more. I know that I cannot use more because of the limit of the buffer pipe (size: 32769 bytes).**

This peripheral device streams data which is not correctly read by bulkTranfer function. I suppose that some data is lost.

I find this: [*In Linux If a process attempts to read from an empty pipe (buffer), then read(2) will block until data is available. If a process attempts to write to a full pipe , then write(2) blocks until sufficient data has been read from the pipe to allow the write to complete.*](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/pipe.7.html)

And based on that, my explanation of the problem is that some data is not written to pipe (buffer) because of blocking flag made by write(2) function. Am I correct? If this is true I could change pipe buffer.

1. My first solution for this problem is greater buffer. [For
   kernel >= 2.6.35, you can change the size of a pipe with `fcntl(fd, F_SETPIPE_SZ, size)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739348/is-it-possible-to-change-the-size-of-a-named-pipe-on-linux) but how can I find `fd` (file descriptor) for
   USB pipes?
2. Second option is to use `ulimit -p SIZE` but parameter `p` for my kernel is not for pipe but process.

Has anyone faced the same problem, any solutions?

Comment: using bulk transfer, am also facing the data loss issue. amlooking into it. I will let you know,once i found the root cause. keep updating the status.

Comment: http://android.serverbox.ch/?p=370  can you go through this conversation? here one logic is presented for handling incoming data. hope it will help you.

Comment: @yokks I've seen that before, it didn't help me.

Comment: I based my stuff of the serverbox stuff with a bit of editing, I went through the same thing. Was frustrating

Comment: found a solution to the data loss issue?

Comment: No and I don't think there is any solution except modifying Android kernel.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android USB Host - bulkTransfer() is losing data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9108548/android-usb-host-bulktransfer-is-losing-data)

Answer (score 2):

You should get a USB data analyzer, Im using this one: http://www.ellisys.com/products/usbex200/index.php

Using something like this really helped me when I was doing the same type of thing, what I found was that you had to do some type of while loop.

For my device I had 64 bytes of data coming in packets to me, the packet would be two control bytes and 62 for data, so for my transfer I had to do something like

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while(bulkTransfer(UsbEndpoint endpoint, byte[] buffer, int length, int timeout) > 2){
    for(int i = 2; i < buffer.length(); i++){
        sb.append((char) buffer[i]);
    }
}
```

something a long these lines worked good for me, i had exactly the same issue and this is how I fixed it. I have more information if you need it. Just comment :). I know this was really frustrating for me to. Im using an Acer Iconia A500 with Android 4.0.3 btw

---

[Transferring larger amounts of data USB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10931558/transferring-larger-amounts-of-data-usb)

[Transferring data USB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10429615/transferring-data-usb)

Comment: I do not have such kind of device. I used only USBlyzer to check transfer between the device and Windows platform. I do not receive any control data in bulkTransfer and probably the maximum size of the packet is 512 bytes. Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

The Android SDK's **UsbEndpoint** object provides a **getMaxPacketSize()** method, allowing you to check what is appropriate for your device.  Generally, the maximum allowable packet size is 64 bytes for USB 'Full-speed' devices and 512 for 'High-speed' devices - far less than 32,768 you are attempting.  Are you perhaps confusing the underlying USB packet size with that of some higher-level protocol?

Comment: I did check the same in my all devices. All devices have packet size 64. I have one Samsung Tablet and everything is working fine in that tablet. But if i use the same code in my Samsung Galaxy S7, then it's not transferring all bytes. Any help? How can i change code to make it working in all devices?

Answer (score 1):

According to the same .pdf gfour posted, I found this paragraph in there:

"The size of the packet will affect the performance and is dependent on the data rate. For very high speed, the largest packet size is needed. For 'real-time' applications that are transferring audio data at 115200 Baud for example, the smallest packet possible is desirable, otherwise the device will be holding up 4k of data at a time. This can give the effect of 'jerky' data transfer if the USB request size is too large and the data rate too low (relatively)."

I'm running into a situation similar to SmartLemon with a FTDI Serial device, so I've been recently looking up ways to alleviate it. This will require me to pretty much write my own functions from scratch while previously I was using a library.

However, it seems that in your case, you could try using bulkTransfer's lowest buffer size instead of shooting for the biggest. You may have tried this already, but maybe not. I see that you say 32768 is the only size, but maybe you only meant the max. It seems weird that it'd only allow one specific size.

Answer (score 0):

According to [AN232B-04_DataLatencyFlow.pdf](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/AppNotes/AN232B-04_DataLatencyFlow.pdf), flow control is needed for high data rates:

> It is strongly encouraged that flow control is used because it is
>   impossible to ensure that the FTDI driver will always be scheduled.

Have you tried using one of the flow control options (RTS/CTS, DTR/DSR, XON/XOFF) to synchronize your data?

Comment: I did not try flow control. I should not use such kind of solution because it will cause additional latency. I analyzed usb transfer between the device and Windows platform and there is no flow control.

Comment: @REACHUS: My situation is similar: reading from the FTDI works fine on my Linux box but loses data on the Android tablet. Since I do about 400kbps of continuous data transfer (audio recording through USB), I suspect that maybe the tablet hardware/kernel/driver combination misbehaves on high data rates. Like you, I know that in my Linux case no flow control is done, but maybe on Android things are different, thus the recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for Bulk transfer issue

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

            StringBuilder strIN = new StringBuilder();

            if (conn.bulkTransfer(epIN, buffer, 4096, 500) >= 0) {
                for (int i = 2; i < 4096; i++) {
                    if (buffer[i] != 0) {
                        strIN.append((char) buffer[i]);

                        textReceiveDataInfo.append(strIN + "\n");
                    } else {
                        l(strIN);
                        break;
                    }
                }

            }
```